# In clojure[script], how to return nearest elements between 2 sorted vectors

Tags: algorithm, clojure, clojurescript

In `clojure[script]`, how to write a function `nearest` that receives two **sorted vectors** `a`, `b` and returns for each element of `a` the nearest element of `b`?

As an example,

```
(nearest [1 2 3 101 102 103] [0 100 1000]); [0 0 0 100 100 100]
```

I would like the solution to be both idiomatic and with good performances: `O(n^2)` is not acceptable!

Comment: Do a binary search `lg m` in the `m` elements of `b` for each of the `n` elements of `a`: `n lg m`. Sort `b` first if that's not guaranteed (m log m).

Comment: You haven't shown any attempt to solve the problem yourself; also, sorted vectors are a pretty bad data structure for this problem. Put things into a sorted-set, for example, and then the "binary search" part of the problem comes for free.

Comment: @amalloy What do you mean by "for free"? Free in the sense that requisite functions are already there? Search in a binary search tree has the same logarithmic complexity characteristics as binary search in a random access array. And if you ask for both headSet and tailSet on a sorted-set to compare, this is twice the work. Or, am I being naive?

Comment: @A.Webb, see my answer below: sorted-set has 2 handy functions: `subseq` and `rsubseq`.

Comment: @viebel Yeah, I just slipped into Java. Those are essentially the same. Each will take logarithmic time to find the appropriate starting place in the binary search tree backing the sorted-set. Since you are doing it twice, this is potentially twice as slow as doing a binary search on the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a binary search or a sorted-set incurs a O(n*log m) time complexity where n is `(count a)` and m `(count b)`.

However leveraging the fact that a and b are sorted the time complexity can be O(max(n, m)).

```
(defn nearest [a b]
  (if-let [more-b (next b)]
    (let [[x y] b
          m (/ (+ x y) 2)
          [<=m >m] (split-with #(<= % m) a)]
      (lazy-cat (repeat (count <=m) x)
        (nearest >m more-b)))
    (repeat (count a) (first b))))


=> (nearest [1 2 3 101 102 103 501 601] [0 100 1000])
(0 0 0 100 100 100 100 1000)
```

Comment: I like it, but if `m >> n` then `n log m` is better than `max(n,m)`. Given your point about both being sorted makes me suspect better is possible in that case too though.

Comment: @A.Webb true but building the sorted-set is `m log m`, so only the binary search apparoach is better when `m >> n`. You're right that b being sorted and being a vector would allow to exponentially skip through b (thanks for the edit btw I pasted the wrong snippet from my repl history).

Comment: @A.Webb I think `O(n log (m/n))` is what you can get so for `m >> n` it simplifies to `O(n log m)` and to `O(n)` otherwise.

Comment: I was thinking `O(n log log m)`, but haven't put pen to paper. Start with the median of `a` find nearest in `b` in `log m` time. Recurse on each half of `a` with split portions of `b`. If a m-size factor of `b` is split each time, you have `O(n log log m)`. If only a constant portion is split off then the half of `a` working on that portion is linear time. If that continues (iterative halves of `a` work on constant size portions of `b`) then you have `O(n)` otherwise `O(log log m)` eventually.

Comment: The above idea is now implemented in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22208189/1756702). I neither tuned, tested, nor analyzed in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Let `n` be `(count a)` and `m` be `(count b)`. Then, if `a` and `b` are *both* ordered, then this can be done in what I believe ought to be `O(n log(log m))` time, in other words, very close to linear in `n`.

First, let's re-implement `abs` and a binary-search (improvements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8949837/1756702)) to be independent of host (leveraging a native, e.g. Java's, version ought to be significantly faster)

```
(defn abs [x] 
  (if (neg? x) (- 0 x) x))

(defn binary-search-nearest-index [v x]
  (if (> (count v) 1)
    (loop [lo 0 hi (dec (count v))]
      (if (== hi (inc lo))
        (min-key #(abs (- x (v %))) lo hi)
        (let [m (quot (+ hi lo) 2)] 
          (case (compare (v m) x) 
             1 (recur lo m) 
            -1 (recur m hi)
             0 m))))
    0))
```

If `b` is sorted, a binary search in `b` takes `log m` steps. So, mapping this over `a` is a `O(n log m)` solution, which for the pragmatist is likely good enough.

```
(defn nearest* [a b]
  (map #(b (binary-search-nearest-index b %)) a))
```

However, we can also use the fact that `a` is sorted to divide and conquer `a`.

```
(defn nearest [a b]
  (if (< (count a) 3)
    (nearest* a b)
    (let [m (quot (count a) 2)
          i (binary-search-nearest-index b (a m))] 
      (lazy-cat
        (nearest (subvec a 0 m) (subvec b 0 (inc i))) 
        [(b i)]
        (nearest (subvec a (inc m)) (subvec b i))))))
```

I believe this ought to be `O(n log(log m))`. We start with the median of `a` and find nearest in `b` in `log m` time. Then we recurse on each half of `a` with split portions of `b`. If a `m`-proportional factor of b are split each time, you have O(n log log m). If only a constant portion is split off then the half of `a` working on that portion is linear time. If that continues (iterative halves of a work on constant size portions of `b`) then you have `O(n)`.

Comment: Note: If tuning, you'd want a higher count threshold on `a` to fall back on `nearest*` in the recursion and to fall back on the `O(max(n,m))` [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22209883/1756702) by @cgrand in the recursion when `m <= cn` for suitable `c`, perhaps `c = 4` for a start.

Comment: Nice solution. Like me you implicitely assumed that b is strictly increasing.

Comment: @cgrand Inspired by yours. Increasing, yes. Strictly so? I wasn't thinking about duplicates because I was regarding `b` as adjacent intervals, but I think our solutions are tolerant of them. Or, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Upon analysis my bug suspicion doesn't hold – even for mine. If your complexity is effectively `O(n log (log m))` then for practical purposes it's `O(n)` since we can consider `log (log m)` bounded. No?

Comment: @cgrand Yes, for current computation models (limited by atoms in the universe), log(log m) is effectively bounded by a small constant, around 8. For things we are generally interested in, around 4-5.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @amalloy, I have found this [interesting idea by Chouser](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/quEzEM_ndCY) and wrote this solution:

```
(defn abs[x]                         
  (max x (- x)))                     

(defn nearest-of-ss [ss x]           
  (let [greater (first (subseq ss >= x))
        smaller (first (rsubseq ss <= x))]
    (apply min-key #(abs (- % x)) (remove nil? [greater smaller]))))

(defn nearest[a b]
  (map (partial nearest-of-ss (apply sorted-set a)) b))
```

Remark: It's important to create the `sorted-set` only once, in order to avoid performance penalty!