# Logarithmic search for multiple items in sorted list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, time-complexity, binary-search

Simply put, is there a logarithmically efficient algorithm to search for *multiple* items in a sorted list?

List:

- A
- C
- F
- L
- Q
- R
- T
- U
- V
- X

Search keys: F, M, R

Desired result: F, R

Comment: which complexity you desire to obtain?

Comment: See top two answers here http://stackoverflow.com/q/22205858/1756702.

Answer (score 1):

Given k keys and a sorted list of n objects, perform k independent binary searches for a total complexity of O(k log n).

Do you need faster than that? If so, what type of better complexity are you looking for?